# Why do I get redirected to media/wysiwyg/... after login?

Tags: magento-1.8

I noticed that I get redirected to "*media/wysiwyg/kategorie_bilder/neue-produkte.jpg*" after submiting the login form of my website?

This leads to a "sorry page not found" site.

How can I find out why this is happening?